# Understanding the Fix datatype in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, free-monad, fixpoint-combinators

In [this article](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html) about the Free Monads in Haskell we are given a Toy datatype defined by:

```
data Toy b next =
    Output b next
  | Bell next
  | Done
```

Fix is defined as follows:

```
data Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))
```

Which allows to nest Toy expressions by preserving a common type:

```
Fix (Output 'A' (Fix Done))              :: Fix (Toy Char)
Fix (Bell (Fix (Output 'A' (Fix Done)))) :: Fix (Toy Char)
```

I understand how fixed points work for regular functions but I'm failing to see how the types are reduced in here. Which are the steps the compiler follows to evaluate the type of the expressions?

Comment: Try to compare that to the plain recursive type definition `data ToyR b = OutputR b (ToyR b) | BellR (ToyR b) | DoneR`. You'll find that they have the same values, except that the `Fix` variant has an additional `Fix` constructor after each `Toy` constructor. This is needed to fold the type from `Toy b (Fix (Toy b))` to `Fix (Toy b)`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'll make a more familiar, simpler type using `Fix` to see if you'll understand it.

Here's the list type in a normal recursive definition:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

Now, thinking back at how we use `fix` for functions, we know that we have to pass the function to itself as an argument. In fact, since `List` is recursive, we can write a simpler nonrecursive datatype like so:

```
data Cons a recur = Nil | Cons a recur
```

Can you see how this is similar to, say, the function `f a recur = 1 + recur a`? In the same way that `fix` would pass `f` as an argument to itself, `Fix` passes `Cons` as an argument to itself. Let's inspect the definitions of `fix` and `Fix` side-by-side:

```
fix :: (p -> p) -> p
fix f = f (fix f)

-- Fix :: (* -> *) -> *
newtype Fix f = Fix {nextFix :: f (Fix f)}
```

If you ignore the fluff of the constructor names and so on, you'll see that these are essentially exactly the same definition!

---

For the example of the `Toy` datatype, one could just define it recursively like so:

```
data Toy a = Output a (Toy a) | Bell (Toy a) | Done
```

However, we could use `Fix` to pass itself into itself, replacing all instances of `Toy a` with a second type parameter:

```
data ToyStep a recur = OutputS a recur | BellS recur | DoneS
```

so, we can then just use `Fix (ToyStep a)`, which will be equivalent to `Toy a`, albeit in a different form. In fact, let's demonstrate them to be equivalent:

```
toyToStep :: Toy a -> Fix (ToyStep a)
toyToStep (Output a next) = Fix (OutputS a (toyToStep next))
toyToStep (Bell next) = Fix (BellS (toyToStep next))
toyToStep Done = Fix DoneS

stepToToy :: Fix (ToyStep a) -> Toy a
stepToToy (Fix (OutputS a next)) = Output a (stepToToy next)
stepToToy (Fix (BellS next)) = Bell (stepToToy next)
stepToToy (Fix (DoneS)) = DoneS
```

---

You might be wondering, "Why do this?" Well usually, there's not much reason to do this. However, defining these sort of simplified versions of datatypes actually allow you to make quite expressive functions. Here's an example:

```
unwrap :: Functor f => (f k -> k) -> Fix f -> k
unwrap f n = f (fmap (unwrap f) n)
```

This is really an incredible function! It surprised me when I first saw it! Here's an example using the `Cons` datatype we made earlier, assuming we made a `Functor` instance:

```
getLength :: Cons a Int -> Int
getLength Nil = 0
getLength (Cons _ len) = len + 1

length :: Fix (Cons a) -> Int
length = unwrap getLength
```

This essentially is `fix` for free, given that we use `Fix` on whatever datatype we use!

Let's now imagine a function, given that `ToyStep a` is a functor instance, that simply collects all the `OutputS`s into a list, like so:

```
getOutputs :: ToyStep a [a] -> [a]
getOutputs (OutputS a as) = a : as
getOutputs (BellS as) = as
getOutputs DoneS = []

outputs :: Fix (ToyStep a) -> [a]
outputs = unwrap getOutputs
```

This is the power of using `Fix` rather than having your own datatype: generality.

Comment: So how does an object of type `Cons a Int` ever get created, if all I have is a `Fix (Cons a)` and a function (`getLength`) `Cons a int -> Int`?
The only way I can get an `Int` from anything else is by using the `getLength` function, but for that, I already need a `Cons a Int`, which I don't have (I only have a `Fix (Cons a)`).

Comment: I get that if I have a `Nil` of ANY type, I can produce an `Int` 0, so in particular I could take a `Fix (Cons a)` and produce an `Int` if the value happens to be `Nil`. However, `getLength` is defined only for an input of type `Cons a Int`, even though `Nil` happens to be valid value for this type as well.

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer by studying this post: https://medium.com/@olxc/catamorphisms-and-f-algebras-b4e91380d134.

Essentially, I forgot about `fmap`. Given our `length` function (`Fix (Cons a) -> Int`), it constructs a lifted function with type `Cons (Fix (Cons a)) -> Cons a Int`, so the magic happens there, where a `Nil` of type `Fix (Cons a)` gets "mapped" to a `Nil` of type `Cons a Int` by essentially doing nothing. :)

Comment: The definition of unwrap is not type-correct; you need to apply the accessor method of Fix to n first. See here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Catamorphisms